# GC over limit exceeded when using Spring integration executor channel

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, garbage-collection, spring-integration

```
   I have got the below exception , I suspect heap memory is full so GC exception was thrown . Kindly explain if any other perspective for the below application solution


  2017:06:07 21:18:36.275 [loginputtaskexecutor-7] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$3.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:333)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:93)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded


  **Application flow in detail :**
```

Spring integration application build to listen message from ActiveMQ , after consuming message from ActiveMQ it will be handed over to input channel (Executor channel) which has subscriber as service activator . In Service Activator message is converted to json then stored to Cassandra . @ transaction was mentioned on the Service activator method .

With the above solution , I thought of breaking Message transaction flow by implementing executor channel , after message consumed it will be handed over to executor channel and the transaction ends . after then threads in executor channel would take care of performing parallel write to cassandra.

Is there any better way to write as fast as possible for large volume of data to casandra using java spring integration

Comment: That kind of setup usually requires Hadoop and Cassandra integration. This will at least split your files into different machines.

Answer (score 1):

If the data sink can't keep up, add a limit to the queue size in the TaskExecutor and use a `CallerRunsPolicy` or `CallerBlocksPolicy` when the queue is full.

That will naturally throttle the workload at the rate the sink can deal with.